# Matplotlib: assign an ever different colour

Tags: python, colors, matplotlib

In Matplotlib, I have several sets of points to **fill in with different colours**, one per set. Now, the number of sets varies, so I would like to make sure that that the same colour doesn't appear more than once in the same plot.

Right now I just do:

```
colors = itertools.cycle(['r','g','b','c','y','m'])
# ...
ax.plot(Xs_for_a_set, Ys_for_a_set, c=colors.next())
```

... but I am limited to that number of colors. From the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html) I don't get how to specify a random color in RGB...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the color as a hex value in a string.

```
color = '#eeefff'
```

Using this you essentially have access to all colors via RGB and can create as many colors as you need

Comment: Ok, so should I feed it random hex number within some predefined range?

Comment: It's OK, I just noticed I can use HTML colours, so I'll simply copy and paste several of them and will use those. ;)

Comment: Great, glad that will work.  But to your first question.  Yes you could start with some basic colors but then as you need more slightly vary the HEX value.  For example... FF0000 is pure red.  If you needed another color, FF9999 is a "lighter red".  You could apply this principle to all colors and have A LOT of color possibilities